# How can I chain .get()s without a NoneType has no attribute 'get'?

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
req = { "foo": True }
if req.get("bar").get("baz") != "qux":
    print("Not Found")
```

I expect this to print `Not Found`, because there is no `bar` containing a `baz` containing `qux`. Instead, it fails with an exception:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

How can this be avoided?

Comment: Uhh, What is `req`?

Comment: Refer [How to create minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For one, you need a non-null return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.get("bar").get("baz")` only works if the first `get` returns a dictionary with the right key

```
In [182]: req = {'bar': {'baz': 'foo'}}
In [183]: req.get('bar')
Out[183]: {'baz': 'foo'}
In [184]: req.get('bar').get('baz')
Out[184]: 'foo'
```

That is the second `get` applies to the object returned by the first.

```
In [185]: req = { "foo": True }
In [186]: req.get('bar')
# returned None
```

Another way to write this would be:

```
req['bar']['baz']    # req must be a nested dictionary
```

`get` takes a `default`, which could be another dictionary.  In fact it could return the dictionary itself - repeatedly:

```
In [187]: req.get('bar', req)
Out[187]: {'foo': True}
In [188]: req.get('bar', req).get('baz')
In [189]: req.get('bar', req).get('baz', req)
Out[189]: {'foo': True}
In [190]: req.get('bar', req).get('baz', req).get('foo')
Out[190]: True
```

This would return your `NotFound`:

```
In [193]: req.get('bar', {}).get('baz', 'fppbar')
Out[193]: 'fppbar'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to chain `.get()`s, pass `{}` as the default for all but the last:

```
if req.get("result", {}).get("action") != "music.play":
```

That way if `req` has no `result`, the first `get()` returns `{}`, which *does* in turn have a `.get()` method.

Answer (score 0):

NoneType means that instead of an instance of whatever Class or Object you think you're working with, you've actually got None. That usually means that an assignment or function call up above failed or returned an unexpected result.

Please refer this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949265/6332980

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your call to the `req.get()` function returned `None`, which means a null reference. Therefore, in that case, you are trying to access the `get` property of a null reference, which cannot be done.